# Automatically rotate through content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I have 7 graphs that are accessible to me through a web site. I want to develop my own web application that automatically cycles through each of these graphs, so I can display them on a huge monitor.

I want the functionality to be similar to an image carousel but it would be for web pages instead of images. What are my options? A jQuery plugin? AJAX and an iframe? Keep in mind that I want the data to be live while I display it.

Comment: A website powerpoint presentation?

Comment: and are these all separate websites or pages within the same website?

Comment: They're all pages within the same website. Keep in mind they're big pages and take a few seconds to initially load and a couple seconds to refresh.

Comment: lastly, what do you mean by "automatically"? timer based... or playback control based?

Comment: A little bit of both. I want it to rotate every 30 seconds but potentially have the ability for start/stop buttons as well as next/previous buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript, and a Frame with a simple timer to load it.

Nothing complex needed,

In the title frame set add this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var toShow;
var URL = new Array ('http://www.google.com','www.yahoo.com','www.bit.ly');

function setupTimer() {
   toShow = 0;
   loadNext();
   var t=setTimeout("loadNext()", 3000);
}
function loadNext(){
    parent.reportframe.location=URL[toShow];
    toShow++;
    if (toShow>3) toShow = 0;
}
</script>

<body onLoad="setupTimer()">
```

Then it will keep reloading the frames.

I just wrote this, did not test it, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: btw, i really like your idea, and if Joseph answers with something better, I might have to use it :)  I use nagios to monitor some servers, and it would be nice to use this actually, on the computer we use to monitor the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5dazE/5/show

That's a basic slideshow.  You can add or remove sites and then press play.  It will rotate every 30 seconds.  the code can be fond here: http://jsfiddle.net/5dazE/5

it could use more work, but I am in agreement with @nycynik.  It is a great idea.